# QTableWidget style per QTableWidgetItem

Tags: css, qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I'm using a simple `QTableWidget` to display some `QTableWidgetItems`, which look like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+
|             | some text 1 |
| some number +-------------+
|             | some text 2 |
+-------------+-------------+
|             | some text 1 |
| some number +-------------+
|             | some text 2 |
+-------------+-------------+
```

I know that I can draw a border around the `QTableWidgetItems` by setting a stylesheet for the `QTableWidget` like

```
QTableView::item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

but this is applied for all the `QTableWidgetItems`. I'd like to draw the border only for the "some number" and "some text 2" items.

Is it possible to do so while sticking to the use of the `QTableWidget` and `QTableWisgetItem`s? I can't use `QObject::setProperty` set some property to identify the items in the style sheet, because `QTableWidgetItem`s are no `QObject`s …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use delegate, example

```
class MyDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
  public:
    MyDelegate( QObject *parent ) : QItemDelegate( parent ) { }
    void paint( QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index ) const;
};

void MyDelegate::paint( QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index ) const
{
    QItemDelegate::paint( painter, option, index );
    painter->setPen( Qt::red );
    painter->drawLine( option.rect.topLeft(), option.rect.bottomLeft() );
   // What line should you draw
   // painter->drawLine( option.rect.topLeft(), option.rect.topRight() );
   // painter->drawLine( option.rect.topLeft(), option.rect.bottomLeft() );
}
...

        m_TableWidgetClass->setItemDelegateForRow(row, new MyDelegate( this));
        //m_TableWidgetClass->setItemDelegateForColumn(column, new MyDelegate( this));
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot :-)